# Can I apply for a masters degree in Canada with a three years bachelors degree from India?

Tags: degree, international-students, bachelor, canada

I have a three years bachelors degree from a university in India(Top 10 by NIRF ranking). I want to do my masters in Canada but I have heard that a 4 years bachelor's degree is required.
The thing is, my 3 years bachelor's degree has the same amount of credit compared to a 4 years bachelor's degree. So in this case, am I eligible or not?

Comment: You probably need to ask the institute you want to apply to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most international universities the requirements for admission generally specify that the candidate should have passed out of a recognised institution with an undergraduate degree and do not impose the duration of the undergraduate course. However if there is an age barrier you can do an internship for a year.

It is very unusual for universities to question the duration of the undergraduate course, please verify your source and you should always contact the admissions office of the universities through email to enquire about such matters, after all they are here to help and most enquiries will get a response within 24 hours.